# Woocommerce Cart crashes on shipping update for non-uk shipping

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

The problem is that all our international users can't purchase anything because when they add their postcode/zipcode from outside the UK, the cart page goes blank.

When I inspect the console it gives me the following error, every time I try to enter update the shipping address.

```
POST http://crowntrent.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_checkout 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:4
m.extend.ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:4
b.submit @ checkout.min.js?ver=2.3.13:1
m.event.dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:3
```

I'm using Woocommerce 2.3.13.

The website is http://crowntrent.co.uk

I'm using the Flatsome UX theme.

[image: Cart after updating with foreign postcode]

Comment: Can you reproduce the error with all extensions/plugins disabled and with a default theme?

Comment: I have a feeling this lives in your shipping/purchase settings (i.e. based on zip). Do you restrict shipping in any way based on address?